# outlook macro - why doesn't this delete all items from deleted folder?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the following macro in outlook to clear my deleted folder.  its strange as it doesn't seem to delete all entries.  I have to run this a few times for it to clear to deleted items folder. (usually 2 or 3 times).  Each time the number of deleted items in the folder does get reduced but I don't understand why everything doesn't get wiped out in the first go.

Here is my code; Anything wrong?

```
Public Sub EmptyDeletedEmailFolder()

    Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim deletedFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim item As Object
    Dim entryID As String

    Set outApp = CreateObject("outlook.application")
    Set deletedFolder = outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems)

    For Each item In deletedFolder.Items
        item.Delete             ' Delete from mail folder
    Next

    Set item = Nothing
    Set deletedFolder  = Nothing
    Set outApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
For i = deletedFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
    deletedFolder.Items(i).Delete             '' Delete from mail folder
Next
```

There can be problems with deleting items from a collection.

Comment: this kinda worked but there is a bug in it. i will edit your answer with the fix . .

Answer (score 1):

By deleting the objects in the collection "underneath" the iterator, it couldn't really go over each item in the collection because the collection was changing.  Remou came up with a really good way that will be guaranteed to continuously delete items in the collection as long as there are items left.  Just don't be deleting items yourself while the method runs or you could run into prolems.